# Decimal Format separator

Tags: android, parsing, decimalformat, decimal-point

I have a problem with formatting decimal values for localizing in Spanish (and other European languages, as well) when the decimal separator for Spain comes out as a comma `,`.
How can I get the decimal separator as dot `.`?

Here is the code I used for formatting a decimal number

```
    DecimalFormat twoDecimalForm = null;
     twoDecimalForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
     DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().setDecimalSeparator('.');
    String valueInDecimal = twoDecimalForm.format(0.005 * progressValue);
//Exception here 
 Log.d(TAG,"valueInDecimal" + Double.valueOf(valueInDecimal));
```

I am getting a comma `,` instead of  of a dot `.`
A workaround can be replace the comma with `.`.

But is there any other solution?

Comment: Many countries use a comma as the decimal seperator so it would be better to just allow for this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html

Comment: @KenWolf I am doing some maths operation on the above values in may places which is returning `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double:`

Comment: Simply, don't convert to number: `Log.d(TAG,"valueInDecimal = " + valueInDecimal.replace(",", ".");`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Every place i do math operation i need to add replace code; which is not good right?!

Comment: Do every math operation you want. Then, simply, **before displaying** the number to a textual View or a Log, convert it to a string and replace the comma with a dot. EASY.

Comment: Thanks @FrankN.Stein. But it is not possible to do math operation on say number like 8,97(8.97).:)

Comment: You are kidding me... you do math operations like Double c = Double a (= 8.97) * Double b (= 1.5). result: c = 13.455 and THEN convert c as string and show it replacing the comma with dot. What is so difficult to understand?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Cool :).Thanks. Doing same right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you getting data from web then ask your web developer to pass data as per your requirement, then your problem gets resolved or you can go with replace option.

Comment: It's android project. If locale set to Spain/Europe then value will be coming with comma separated.

Comment: How are you getting data inside app? Its already store in app or getting from server side?

Comment: The data which i am parsing in decimal format is giving decimal separator as comma which leads us to wrong math operation

Comment: before going for math operation you can replace the , with .  I am asking from where you are getting data?